# Implementing pusher inside a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, pusher

I have a chrome extension that displays a small popup which is basically an iframe that links to my website. It is so that the user can access a few selected information anytime by clicking on the extension button.

We also have a notification system in place built using [pusher.com](http://pusher.com) that sends out notifications if an important event happens within the users account. We have the basic pusher code as follows

```
var encoded_user_id = "jmxk5y3y"; //static user id for demo purpose
var pusher = new Pusher('222222222222222222');
var channel = pusher.subscribe(encoded_user_id);

channel.bind('notifications_count_update', function(data){
    //set the notification count in DOM
});
```

So the above binding is done on the encoded user id, which becomes a means for communication and works fine for displaying notifications within the website.

What I am missing is a way to integrate the above pusher code within the chrome extension so that new notification numbers can be shown as "Badge Text" on the button of the extension. And since all the extension does is display an iframe I cannot access session info (the user id) inside the frame to use for listening of messages.

How should I proceed solving this?

Comment: ["externally_connectable" + sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)?

Comment: Wow. that looks like something that could solve my issue,
thanks I will give it try now...

Comment: I had a look at the solution and It seems I could use it to send notifications to the extension when the user is on my website. However the user can get notifications even though he is not on the site.

How should I go about implementing that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Pusher Product Hunt Chrome Extension](https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-realtime-producthunt-extension) that shows the badge-style notifications.

Take a look at [background.js](https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-realtime-producthunt-extension/blob/master/background.js) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had a chance to look at the extension, and it involves subscribing to a global channel to which is pushed a new message.

Although quiet similar to what I was looking for, it does not actually resolve my problem as I need to pass messages to a particular channel, In my case the encoded user id, so that only that user receives the notification.

Comment: So is real question is how do you access session information from a specific website from a chrome extension? You then use this session information as the name of the Pusher channel?